# HTML app similar to Air Sketch

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, connection

Is it possible to create an app similar to the iPad app Air Sketch using HTML and Javascript? The app to be developed enables the user to draw in a canvas on a mobile device and could broadcast it to other devices by accessing the IP given by the app in a web browser. I will be using PhoneGap as well to port the HTML app to native platforms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase and AngularJS provide a basic framework for the kind of functionality that you are talking about.  One of the apps showing off AngularFire (The official integration package for these packages) is a drawing app much like you describe.

App like what you want: https://www.firebase.com/how-it-works.html

Firebase: https://www.firebase.com/index.html
Angular: http://angularjs.org/

Drawing Example detail: https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#session/pjswe8jan7m

Comment: Thanks. This does seem the way to go. I would also like to know if is it possible to have the app act as a server instead of using a backend web service. It would work over a WiFi network similar to Air Sketch, without needing access to a web service.

Comment: According to the firebase documentation, yes, there is no need for a server but the configuration is a little more complicated. From their site "Firebase apps can be written entirely with client-side code, update in real-time out-of-the-box, scale automatically, and provide strong data security."

Comment: I should also point out that Firebase can be used in phonegap/cordova apps as it is a webkit compatible javascript library.

Comment: Doesn't that simply mean that Firebase already provide their server service, allowing you to entirely write your code in client-side?

Comment: You have to have some sort of server side router to connect clients.  It is certainly possible to use the native support of Phonegap for this functionality but Firebase just makes it easier.  A word of caution though, utilizing the phonegap functionality for communicating between devices might keep your app from working in a strictly browser setting. The native functionality that phonegap provides for communicating does not work in browsers.